# How do I automatically make symlinks based on a file?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a text file that contains multiple lines of sources and targets.

Example:

```
"/home/desktop/aaa t" "/home/desktop/bbb"
"/home/desktop/ee e" "/home/desktop/aa/rr r"
```

I have tried this:
`cat ../symlinks.txt | xargs -i{} -d\n ln -s {}` but that seems to be broken, and `ln` does not seem to like that.

I need to create a lot of symlinks from a file to the target path, that symlinks to the source. How would I be able to do this, using bash? The paths are currently all surrounded in quotation marks and are a absolute path, since `ln` doesn't seem to be able to take relative paths.

Comment: xargs will pass each line (name and target) as one argument (which makes no sense) regardless of location of given list. besides the double quotes aren't actually quotes but treaten as literally characters (and word splitting still occurs). put your command in a script and run it *sh -x script* to see what is happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the '-I' will will pass the whole input line as a single argument, consider using the '-L1', which will use the default `xargs` word splitting, which will support quotes, and backslash.

```
xargs -L1 ln -s < ../symlinks.txt
```

From `xargs` man:

> ... xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be  protected  with  double  or  single quotes  or  a backslash) or newlines ...

Note regarding relative path:
There is no reason that `ln` will not work with relative symlinks. Try the following

```
echo '"a b" c' | xargs -L1 ln -s
```

Which will create a symlink 'c' to (non-existent) file 'a b' in the current folder.